# C# Keeping end-of-string punctuation in a string

Tags: string, special-characters, punctuation

I have been searching for hours and cannot for the life of me figure out how to keep "Some question?" from turning into "?Some question"...  in a messagebox, in a textbox, in a string[].  I've tried using \?  I've tried appending the text +"?" and + "/?"  and nothing's working! Please Help!

EDIT:

This is in C#. I have written plenty of code but the problem is very simple:

```cs
string questiontoask = "Some Question?";
MessageBox.Show(questiontoask); // this is just an example, I realize there are no buttons.
```

Output: ?Some Question

Or:

```cs
textBox1.Lines = somestrarray;
```

Output: Every line with any kind of punctuation " . , ) ( > < [ ] { } ..."
converts automatically to a punctuation before string format...

This is extremely frustrating.

EDIT2:

After reading some answers and doing sometesting I discovered that my textboxes are getting automatically set to RightToLeft = yes.  In the properties window it says "no" and in the .Designer.cs  there is nothing set.  but this still doesn't explain how it's happening in a message box.  This has happened in two separate solutions, but when I make a new one there is NO ERROR!!!!!! wtf.

Comment: In which programming language you need help and did you wrote some code?

Comment: The question has been updated ^^

Comment: does the same issue occur if you use the verbatim notation? string `questiontoask = @"Some Question?";`

Comment: I haven't tried the @"verbatim" method.  I would have to find a way to do it programatically as I am combining strings programatically.  This might be a temp fix, but something is causing this glitch and I want to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eurika!! After trying the suggestions, and doing further debugging, I have found the solution!  Or rather the problem... Somewhere along the lines I had set the Main form's RightToLeft property to YES... and since my application is Mdi-based, all of my mdichilren, and all of their components' RightToLeft property was automatically acting as YES until I changed each manually.  Solution:  Set MainForm.RightToLeft to NO.  Now on further note, I do want some controls to be right to left, but I want to put the punctuation on the right... @"verbatim?" solved this for me.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple form containing nothing but a button triggering your example:

```java
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String questiontoask = "Some Question?";
        MessageBox.Show(questiontoask);
    }
}
```

This *does* give the expected result, namely `Some Question?` - this problem seems to lie within your project, not C#/.NET. (Tried with 4.0 & 4.5)

This leaves you with two options: Also create a sample project and see if you can reproduce the issue, then track down the difference if you can't. Or provide us with more relevant information / a demo which actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: Okay, so I tried what you suggested, and you are correct. After a bit of testing i discovered the problem, see newest Edit^^^.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Thread.CurrentUICulture` property.  If it's not `en-GB` or `en-US`, that could be the culprit.

Comment: From what I researched, punctuation rules are not part of the .NET globalization.

Comment: It has to do with the "Right to left reading order" flag.  As an example, open Notepad and type your text into there, and then right click and check the "Right to left reading order".

Comment: This explains a lot, thank you!!!  My current problem is when I populate a textbox via .Lines with a string[].  I tried the Notepad thing and it's doing the exact same thing!  Any idea how to keep the Right to left reading order but put the punctuation on the right???

Comment: You can modify the `RightToLeft` property on the `TextBox`.

Comment: I discovered the real problem Edit2^^^ . I will try the Thread.CurrentUICulture thing, but I don't think it's related.

Comment: You should be able to see it in the debugger.  You may have to include the full namespace: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentUICulture`.  Or you can output it to your debugger using `Debug.WriteLine()`.